# Python Kivy: adding a FigureCanvas widget through a custom event

Tags: python, user-interface, graphics, callback, kivy

I am new to Kivy and GUIs in general and I am having a hard time understanding some simple concepts of Kivy callbacks logic. I want to make a simple app to read a CSV and plot a graph from it, so I want the widget that opens the file to trigger a function that adds a FigureCanvaKivyAgg widget that shows the figure.

On my source code I disabled the plotting from the CSV readed as it does not add to the issue at hand. You will see that I tried different ways to trigger the callback, but I only accomplish to trigger the custom event, it does not communicate with the callback nor add the FigureCanva Widget to the Layout.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
 
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg

 
from shark_plot import shark_plot

import os
 

csv = {'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'y':[2,4,6,8,6,12]}

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_event')
 
        container = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        
 
        filechooser = FileChooserIconView()
    
        filechooser.bind(on_selection=lambda x: self.selected(filechooser.selection))
        print(filechooser.selection,filechooser.path)
 
        open_btn = Button(text='open', size_hint=(1, .2))
        open_btn.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.open(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection))

        box = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, .5))

        box.bind(on_event= self.action)
        
        # if len(filechooser.path[0])>0:
        #     # box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
 
        container.add_widget(filechooser)
        container.add_widget(open_btn)
        container.add_widget(box)
        self.add_widget(container)
 
    def on_event(self):
        print("Event triggered?")
        plt.show()
        canva = (FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return canva

    def action(self):
        print('Action executed??')
        canva = (FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        self.cb.ask_update()
        return canva
    
    def open(self, path, filename):
        print(filename)
        if len(filename) > 0:
            selected_path = os.path.join(path, filename[0])
            print(selected_path)
            df=pd.read_csv(selected_path)
            # fig = shark_plot(df)
            fig = plt.plot(csv['x'],csv['y'])
            g=self.dispatch('on_event')
            
            print(type(df))
            # print(f.read())
        return fig
 
    def selected(self, filename):
        print("selected: %s" % filename[0])
 
def on_event_callback():
        print("Action Triggered??")
        canva = (FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        subbox = BoxLayout()
        subbox.add_widget(canva)
        return subbox


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Hope that the question is clear, it is my first time making such here :)

Please reach out for any clarifications.

Comment: I don't really get it clear, "on_event" is bound to "action", so whenever happens an event you call "action".  Could you exaplain me what function you want to call (as a callback) and from where you want to call it?

Comment: So, I want "on_event" to trigger one function that adds a FigureCanvasKivyAgg to the sub BoxLayout, declared as "box". The figure to be displayed in the FigureCanvas is the graph "fig" generated by the open function.

I think that I am just not getting how the callbacks interact with the Widgets and Layouts...

Answer (score 0):

on_event() will run via the dispatch() statement, but there is no connection from on_event() to the add_widget() statement in on_event_callback(), so that never happens. You can either put add_widget() directly in on_event(), or, if you want a separate function, then call it directly from open() without using the kivy register and dispatch().

```
    def on_event(self):
        canva = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())
        self.add_widget(canva)

    def on_event_callback(self,canva):
        self.add_widget(canva)

    def open(self, path, filename):
        # open data files here etc to load self.csv
        plt.plot(self.csv['x'],self.csv['y'])
        self.dispatch('on_event')
        canva2 = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())
        self.on_event_callback(canva2)
```